# Overriding template in woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

In my plug-in i'm trying to override part of the theme's template with a template of my own but I'm struggling to get it to work.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'demo_page_template');

function demo_page_template($template) {

    if ( is_product() ) {
  $template = untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . 'templates/woocommerce/single-product.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
```

I have added the appropriate files and folders but I'm not getting any reaction.

thanks for reading, appreciate any help I can get.